# What to do if I find residuals (=deviance) patterns after applying a GAMMA GLM in R?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, residuals, gamma-distribution

I have activity data for 6 individuals (`ID`) obtained using two different formulas (`RMS.X16` and `VeDBA.X16`), and I want to test which of those formulas fit better to my response variable `RMS.V13AP`.

Here you can see the relationship of `RMS.X16` and `VeDBA.X16` with `RMS.V13AP`.

[image]

Below you can see also a histogram of my response variable `RMS.V13AP` (upper left). In the graph appears also the histogram of my response variable with different transformations.

[image]

As you can see, `RMS.V13AP` is positive and continuous, so I decided to make a GLM using a Gamma distribution with a log link. I included `ID` as a fixed effect and not as a random effect because I want to test if the relationship changes among individuals. To answer the main question (differences between formulas for predicting `RMS.V13AP`), I did this:

```r
mod1 <- glm(RMS.V13AP ~ VeDBA.X16+ID,data = 
            FormulaValidation.57s, family=Gamma(link=log))
mod2 <- glm(RMS.V13AP ~ RMS.X16+ID, data = FormulaValidation.57s, 
            family=Gamma(link=log))

AIC(mod1,mod2)
     df      AIC
mod1  8 3831.017
mod2  8 3812.568

ED.mod1 <- 100* (1-(mod1$deviance/mod1$null.deviance)) # Explained deviance
ED.mod1
[1] 62.3574

ED.mod2 <- 100* (1-(mod2$deviance/mod2$null.deviance))
ED.mod2
[1] 62.54075
```

It seems that the formula `RMS` fits better my data, however differences between `RMS` and `VeDBA` are very low according to the explained deviance.

My doubts arise when I make some diagnostic plots. First, I show the plots I usually find in literature:

```r
mod1.diag <- glm.diag(mod1)
mod2.diag <- glm.diag(mod2)
glm.diag.plots(mod1,mod1.diag)
glm.diag.plots(mod2,mod2.diag)
```

[image]

After some searching, I found also this approach to explore residuals (simulations):

```r
library(DHARMa)
sim_nbz  <-  simulate(mod2, nsim =1000)
str(sim_nbz)
sim_nbz = do.call(cbind, sim_nbz)
head(sim_nbz)
sim_res_nbz = createDHARMa(simulatedResponse = sim_nbz, 
                           observedResponse = 
                           FormulaValidation.57s$RMS.V13AP,
                           fittedPredictedResponse = 
                           predict(mod2),
                           integerResponse = FALSE)
plotSimulatedResiduals(sim_res_nbz)
```

[image]

The way I see it, there is clear evidence of residual patterns but I don't know what should be next step.

Should I care about those residual patterns?
Should I transform my response variable and try to use another type of regression?

Comment: Yes, you should care about residual patterns, and they should follow the theoretical form of the model. With respect to the predictors some transformations might help alleviate the patterns you see.